# iText rotation creates pdf which displays out of memory exception

Tags: itext

Following is a code snippet creating a pdf file where pages could be rotated in the resulting file. This works fine for most pdf files. But one particualr pdf file of version 1.6 the page is already rotated by 180, on applying further rotation to it e.g. 90 degress and saving the file causes it to get corrupted. Infact even if you don't rotate the file and simply write it out to another file using iText the file the resulting pdf is corrupted and displays an out of memory exception when opened in Adobe reader.

Why would that happen? Am I missing some sort of compression in the file.

```
private String createPdfFileWithoutForms(final EditStateData[] editStateData, final String directory)
        throws EditingException {

        Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        File pdfFileToReturn = new File(directory + File.separator + UidGenerator.generate() + ".pdf");

        com.lowagie.text.Document document = null;
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        PdfCopy pdfCopy = null;
        PdfReader reader = null;
        PdfDictionary pageDict = null;
        int rotationAngle = 0;
        Map<Integer, Integer> rotationQuadrants = null;

        try {

            document = new com.lowagie.text.Document();
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(pdfFileToReturn);
            pdfCopy = new PdfCopy(document, outputStream);
            pdfCopy.setFullCompression();
            pdfCopy.setCompressionLevel(9);
            document.open();

            for (EditStateData state : editStateData) {
                try {
                    reader = new PdfReader(state.getFileName());
                    reader.selectPages(state.getPages());
                    rotationQuadrants = state.getRotationQuadrants();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                        // Rotation quadrant key is the source page number
                        if (rotationQuadrants.containsKey(state.getPages().get(i - 1))) {
                            rotationAngle = reader.getPageRotation(i);
                            pageDict = reader.getPageN(i);
                            pageDict.put(PdfName.ROTATE,
                                new PdfNumber((rotationAngle 
                                    + rotationQuadrants.get(state.getPages().get(i - 1))) % 360));
                        }

                        document.setPageSize(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(i));
                        document.newPage();
                        // import the page from source pdf
                        PdfImportedPage page = pdfCopy.getImportedPage(reader, i);
                        // add the page to the destination pdf
                        pdfCopy.addPage(page);
                    }
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                    throw new EditingException(e.getMessage(), e);
                } finally {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new EditingException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            if (document != null) {
                document.close();
            }

            if (pdfCopy != null) {
                pdfCopy.close();
            }
            IoUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
        }

        LOGGER.debug("Combining " + editStateData.length + " pdf files took "
            + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " msecs");

        return pdfFileToReturn.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

Comment: I see my name in your code. Please understand that all versions prior to iText 5 are deprecated and as such no longer supported. See http://lowagie.com/itext2

Comment: Can you provide the sample *output PDF* with that issue to inspect?